# Example of a left compatible relation on a semigroup that is not right compatible.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, relations, semigroups

Definition : Let $S$ be a semigroup. let $R$ be a relation on $S$.

- **Left compatibility**: $R$ is left compatible if 
  $$ (\forall a , s ,t \in S)  \ \ (s,t) \in R  \ \ \Rightarrow (as , at) \in R $$
- **Right compatibility**:  $R$ is is right compatible if 
  $$ (\forall a , s ,t \in S)  \ \ (s,t) \in R  \ \ \Rightarrow (sa , ta) \in R $$

> Give a counterexample of a relation which is left compatible but not right compatible. Similarly, a  counter example of a relation which is right compatible but not left compatible.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The reference to your **own recent and somewhat similar question**  found back by J.-E. Pin should absolutely be mentionned in any (seemingly) new related question. It is a matter of respect for others. There is no shame to say, right at the beginning : "I have asked a question (reference such and such) that hasn't been answered properly. I ask a new one that is related but somewhat less/more general (for example, or any other explanation)"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Green's relation $\mathcal{R}$ that you mentioned in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930145/properties-of-greens-equivalence-on-a-semigroup-s) is left compatible (but in general not right compatible). Dually the Green's relation $\mathcal{L}$ is right compatible (but in general not left compatible)